# Gas estimation failed:"transfer amount exceeds spender allowance"

Tags: gas-estimate

I want to execute function Tip and transfer IERC20 Token.
However, this message is shown.

---

Uni::transferFrom: transfer amount exceeds spender allowance { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c556e693a3a7472616e7366657246726f6d3a207472616e7366657220616d6f756e742065786365656473207370656e64657220616c6c6f77616e636500000000", "message": "execution reverted: Uni::transferFrom: transfer amount exceeds spender allowance" } }

---

I think I couldn't approve correctly so this error message has appeared, but I don't know how to fix...
Is there are any good ideas? My code is here.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
    import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
    import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    
    contract Tip is Ownable{
        
        address public token = 0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984;
    
        function approval (uint amount) public {
            IERC20(token).approve(address(this),amount);
        }
        
    
        function tip (address to, uint amount) payable public {
            address from = msg.sender;
            IERC20(token).transferFrom(from,to,amount);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `tip` function is calling `transferFrom` of `token`, in order for it to be able to do that the user calling `tip` has to approve this Tip contract to spend the tokens.

Before calling `tip()`, you need to call token.approve(_TipContractAddress, amountToSpend);. So the `Tip` contract can have the token balance owned by the account calling `approve` spent by it.

Notice this isn't some line of code you can add to the Tip contract. The UI/script you are building has to have the user first do approve on the token, then you can have them call `tip()` on your contract.